# Can't set UINavigationBar Title or place UIButtons in the UINavigationBar when back button is present

Tags: swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am developing an application which will have multiple nested UIViewControllers. I have two views, one is the root view controller with a uibarbuttonitem, with is connected to another UIViewController.

The UIViewController which was segued to does not accept and UIButtons or UIBarButtonItems and I can't seem to set a title to it.

[image: The Storyboard]

I need to place a title and other UIElements in the UINavigationBar but nothing seems to work, and I did not find any solutions online.

The UINavigationBar does not even appear in the view's hierarchy.

[image: Hierarchy]

Thank you for any cooperation.

Comment: @vacawama i have edited the post. Please check again.

Comment: Try adding a UINavigationItem first.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Can you show us, some code?

Comment: Set `self.title = "whatever"` in `viewDidLoad` in your view controller to set the title.  Set right bar button with something like this: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Foo", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleRightBarButton))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.  The Storyboard layout is inconsistent and confusing in the case of ViewControllers in the NavigationController stack.  The first one offers direct access to the NavigationItem but later ones don't.  I suppose that is because there is only one NavigationItem and it needs to be updated dynamically as the ViewControllers are pushed and popped.

The way to deal with this is to do it in code.  When a ViewController is pushed, its `title` property is used to set the title on the navigation bar.  So, in each of your ViewControllers that are in a NavigationController's stack, set its `title` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.title = "titleForThisVC"
```

For the `rightBarButton`, you add it programmatically as well.  If this is your `@IBAction` for the button:

```
@objc func handleRightBarButton() {
    print("right button")
}
```

then you'd add the button like this (again in `viewDidLoad`):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Foo", style: .plain,
     target: self, action: #selector(handleRightBarButton))
```

---

**One last *gotcha* for `UITabBarController`s**

If your NavigationControllers are the children of a `UITabBarController`, then the title that is used in the tab bar will pick up the title from the first ViewController in the stack as set by the code, but only after that tab has first been accessed.  To get around this, the `title` property should also be set for the top ViewControllers in the *Attributes Inspector* in *Interface Builder*